# SML NJ , able to find max real of array, cant get index

Tags: arrays, max, sml, smlnj

i have an array of real values like `[|1.2, 3.4, 5.3, 2.5|]`

```
fun max_arr arr = foldl Real.max (sub (arr, 0)) arr;
```

works fine to find the max value `5.3` .
Then i would expect something like

```
fun max_arri arr = foldli (Real.max(sub (arr, 0))) arr;
```

to successfully return the location of `max value 2`.but it doesn't work.

```
(Error: unbound variable or constructor: max_arri)
```

I went through everything I could find online but the documentation about `sml seems small`...
according to the manual they both take the same data. so what would i need to change?

```
foldli f init arr
foldl f init arr
```

also i dont want to use lists because i change the data alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do not take the same input.

```
foldl  :: (      'a * 'b -> 'b) -> 'b -> 'a array -> 'b
foldli :: (int * 'a * 'b -> 'b) -> 'b -> 'a array -> 'b
```

As we can see from the types, the difference is that `foldli` takes a function that also takes an integer -- the index of the element.

The return type of the two functions are both `'b`, so `foldli` does not return the index. Rather, this expression:

```
foldli (fn (i, a, b) => f (a, b)) init arr
```

Is the exact equivalent of this expression:

```
foldl f init arr
```

Now, if we want to return the index of an element, we need the `'b` in the type of `foldli` to become `int`. However, finding the maximum relies on comparison of elements, so we *also* need the current maximum, just like in your `max_arr` function. The obvious solution is to use a tuple. `'b` now becomes `(real * int)`.

```
(* cElem = current element
 * cI = current index
 *)
fun fmax (i, elem : real, (cElem, cI)) =
  if cElem > elem
  then (cElem, cI)
  else (elem, i)

fun max_arri arr = foldli fmax (sub (arr, 0), 0) arr
```

Of course, this is not the type we want our `max_arri` to return - we only want the index. The loose helper function isn't very nice either, but it's a bit long to have as a lambda. Instead, we wrap it all in a local:

```
local
  fun fmax (i, elem : real, (cElem, cI)) =
    if cElem > elem
    then (cElem, cI)
    else (elem, i)

  fun max_arri' arr = foldli fmax (sub (arr, 0), 0) arr
in
  fun max_arri arr = let val (_, i) = max_arri' arr
                     in i end
end
```

Comment: i m sorry if my follow up question is silly but this is my first sml complete program.. I get syntax error
`Error: syntax error: deleting  LPAREN WILD COMMA
Error: syntax error: deleting ID RPAREN EQUALOP
in i end
end
Error: syntax error: deleting IN ID END`

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have an sml interpreter installed on this computer, so the code is untested. I'll look into it later and let you know what I find.

Comment: i think the problem is fmax  expects 
`int * 'a * (int * 'a)`
 at 
`(i, elem, (cElem, cI))`
but it gets 
`'a`
 from 
`fmax sub(arr,0)`
still not sure how to fix it though

Comment: I have edited the code to a version I have tested on my own system. The problems were: I forgot `val` in my `let-in-end` block. I didn't think of sml's restrictions of polymorphism when it comes to overloaded operators like `>` - it tries to restrict it to `int`. I fixed this by constraining `elem` to have type `real`.